# Getting the results of pdftotext into a php variable, not a text file

Tags: php, pdf-generation

pdftotext takes a PDF file and converts the text into a .txt file.

How would I go about getting pdftotext to send the result to a PHP variable instead of a text file?

I'm assuming I have to run `exec('pdftotext /path/file.pdf')`, but how do I get the result back?

Comment: My `pdftotext` command not running in `exec()` function. Am i missing anything that used in library?

Comment: @SumitMadan  Does anything run in exec() for you.  If not, your issue is there, if others do run then check to make sure pdftotext is installed...

Comment: ya other commands are running and pdftotext is installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to capture stdout/stderr:

```
function cmd_exec($cmd, &$stdout, &$stderr)
{
    $outfile = tempnam(".", "cmd");
    $errfile = tempnam(".", "cmd");
    $descriptorspec = array(
        0 => array("pipe", "r"),
        1 => array("file", $outfile, "w"),
        2 => array("file", $errfile, "w")
    );
    $proc = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes);

    if (!is_resource($proc)) return 255;

    fclose($pipes[0]);    //Don't really want to give any input

    $exit = proc_close($proc);
    $stdout = file($outfile);
    $stderr = file($errfile);

    unlink($outfile);
    unlink($errfile);
    return $exit;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for being dense but...what should I be using the the 2nd and 3rd arguments?

right now I have echo cmd_exec('/usr/local/bin/pdftotext /users/jmr/downloads/test.pdf -');  which returns 1 but when I run the same command normally I get the PDF text onscreen

Comment: Use the variables you want to capture the input into for the second and third argument.

Comment: @altCognito can you please give the line of code for how to call above function and get value?I used it like this and parameter not defined error came out. pr( $this->cmd_exec(" pdftotext /var/www/sample.pdf - "),&$var,&$varr );

Comment: I changed  $stdout = file($outfile); to  $stdout = impode(file($outfile)); Now   Its working. An i used it like this       $this->cmd_exec(' pdftotext /var/www/sample.pdf - ',&$out,&$in ); //Thanks man;
echo $out;

Answer (score 9):

```
$result = shell_exec("pdftotext file.pdf -");
```

The `-` will instruct pdftotext to return the result to stdout instead to a file.